# Will an event trigger non-"active" windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to open multiple windows in Chrome, each of which will have a javascript running listening for a specific event. When that event occurs, I want it to trigger the same response simultaneously in all windows.

I know only one window will be "active", in most browsers the other windows being "greyed out", but I am wondering if they are still listening for events even though only one main window is in view.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the event? I don't quite understand your question. (e.g., if the event you want is a mouse click, it will not fire in other windows because only one windows had an element get clicked)

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using Intercom.js: https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/